# how to create a timer job in a sharepoint 2010 web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm working on a project, and the client wants the data in their sharepoint 2010 webpart to update automatically based on what time it is.  We're using C# to write the code.

I've tried just about every way that the four corners of the internet have provided to come up with a good way to do this, however, I'm stumped.  I'm aware that there are three different timers that come with visual studio 2010 (which is what I'm using).  Is there any way at all to do this?

Here are some of the ways I've tried:

-create a timer job that runs on central admin (this method is covered in several web tutorials), I got the timer job to work, but I can't figure out if there is a way from this to refresh the web part with the new info.  I was basically using the SPJobDefiniton class and a feature.

-tried to use the built in system timer, as covered here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

tried to adapt that to a web part, and that went nowhere.  The web part built, but the timer never ran.

-tried it with System.Threading.Timer, and also went nowhere fast.

Is there any way that someone knows of to get the functionality I want?  Thanks.

Comment: It would be possible to answer your question if you reasonably define "functionality I want", so far it is very unclear why would you need any timers at all... There is good chance that just changing rendering based on DateTime.Now would suffice. If you really need timer jobs sharepoint.stackexchange.com maybe better place to ask.

Comment: see, the site I'm working on has a web page that displays a web part.  There's a back end database and/or sharepoinnt list that has data, and this data has to be pulled from the backend sources and displayed in textboxes and labels on the web part.  The issue is that client wants the app to change the data based on what time of day it is and then, automatically reload the webpart (with no user input) to display the correct data.  A datetime function is a good idea, but only works if the user manually reloads the page.

Comment: BTW, thanks for taking the time to respond Alexei, its greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will have to define an Ajax refresh pane, and then have that panel refresh frequently using Javascript. Remember that HTML is state-less, once delivered to the end-user, there is no further way to arbitrarily push information at them - the user (or javascript) needs to make another request to update.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nothing to do with SharePoint for me...

You probably need client side timer in your JavaScript `window.setTimeout` and force update of whole page (easy, just change window.location) or partial (need some service to pull data from, update part of the page - harder, but better looking).

Server side just render data based on current time...